# Calling pip package files from within pip package? (`No module named 'src.snnalgorithms'`)

Tags: python, import, pip

Whilst in `some_other_package`, I am importing files from the `snnalgorithms` pip package. I received the error:
`No module named 'src.snnalgorithms'`. This is a valid error because that `src.snnalgorithms` file does not exist in the `some_other_package` project from which I was calling the pip package.

As a solution, I can make all the imports in the `snn.algorithms` pip package, relative to itself. Instead of:

```py
from src.snnalgorithms.population.DUMMY import DUMMY
```

One could write:

```py
from snnalgorithms.population.DUMMY import DUMMY
```

However, that implies that each time I want to run the code to briefly verify a minor change, or run the tests after a change, I will have to:

0. Upload the changes into the `pip` package.
1. Re-install the pip package locally to reflect the changes.

This significantly slows down development. Hence I was wondering are there more efficient solutions for this?

Comment: `pip install -e .` (note the dot) installs the package in development mode (where changes are visible to some_other_package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e) for development mode

```
pip install -e .  # Install package locally
```

From [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/#editable-installs):

> Editable installs allow you to install your project without copying any files. Instead, the files in the development directory are added to Python’s import path. This approach is well suited for development and is also known as a “development installation”.
>
> With an editable install, you only need to perform a re-installation if you change the project metadata (eg: version, what scripts need to be generated etc). You will still need to run build commands when you need to perform a compilation for non-Python code in the project (eg: C extensions).

### Example

If you have project: `some_other_package` from which you call pip package `snnalgorithms` you can:

```
cd snnalgorithms
pip install -e .
cd ..
cd some_other_package
python -m src.some_other_package
```

Assuming you use the same conda environment for both packages, both packages will then be able to use your newest changes that have not even been published to pypi.org yet.